# Num Lock key triggers tab?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, kubuntu, numlock, numpad

I recently installed Kubuntu 14.04 and ever since then didn't get my Num Pad to work. I have a Samsung Laptop with a Num Pad (not in a higher layer on the main board, but next to it). The system automatically chose 'Generic Keyboard with 101 keys', which is correct.

I can also use the arrows, pgup, pgdown etc. on the Num Pad. But when I try to activate the Numbers by hitting Num Lock, nothing happens. Instead, it writes a Tabulator in any text editor. In terminal, it activates the command completion, so it seems to be a real tab signal.

It might be an issue with the german NEO layout that I have set up as default, but switching to a different layout didn't help. And yes, I made sure that the option "control mouse cursor with arrow keys" is disabled.

I have no idea what the problem is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try remapping your Num lock in the following way it might work for you. Follow the steps exactly.

Know how your system sees those keys, using the command `xev` and pressing the keys whose id you want to discover.After entering the `xev` just press page up and then press alt+t then you will get the following results. Then use the key code you got on pressing alt+t keys in the command at the end. that's all it will be done. I did this on my laptop and got the below results and so i gave it for reference only. You have to perform action to get your own result as these results vary with computer.

Pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> produces keycode 111, assigned to action `Up`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0xa5, subw 0x0, time 13739005, (165,-16), root(170,32),
state 0x0, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Pressing <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> key gives the following:

```
KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
root 0xc3, subw 0x0, time 13714833, (61,151), root:(63,236),
state 0x10, keycode 112 (keysym 0xff55, Prior), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Once you know the keycode of the keys you would like to use, and the name of the actions you want to perform, you can assign the desired actions to the chosen keys.
The following four commands will produce the desired change, valid only for the present X session:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 112 = Up"
```

To get these changes for every session, after issuing the commands above, create a file called .Xmodmap (or whatever), with the following command:

```
xmodmap -pke > .Xmodmap
```

Then, create a file called .xinitrc in your home directory, containing just the following line:

```
xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

Refer to the site for any doubts: http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/...txkbmap_Method

Comment: Thanks.  The key 77 was indeed assigned to 'Tab'. I changed it and now xev says:  ` KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0x254, subw 0x0, time 580062, (71,430), root:(99,453),
    state 0x0, keycode 77 (keysym 0xff7f, Num_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False `  So, the remapping worked, but the number keys still don't work, even after creating the .xinitrc file and restarting... Actually, I think I should have posted this in a forum, not a Q&A site.